# Extracting Voice Memos from iPhone to iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, audio, voice-memo

I am currently doing some coursework for my exams, and part of my IT project is to record some audio, and assess it. I recorded this audio on my iPhone, and I plan on using Audacity to edit it. I am having a problem with getting the voice memos off my iPhone, and that's preventing me from doing my coursework. Does anyone know what to do? I use iTunes 11.1.3

Comment: I did solve this problem by doing fake "trim" on memos that won't sync. Then they will sync with itunes. Did not find any batch process though, thumb process works slower, but it does.

Answer (score 1):

If you sync your iPhone with iTunes and have the voice memo syncing enabled, then the voice memos will be transferred to your computer when syncing. The voice memos will show in the Voice Memos playlist.

Comment: I have synced my iPhone, but the Voice Memos folder in iTunes is empty.

Comment: @user3775989 Have you enabled Voice Memos syncing in the Music tab for your device in iTunes?

Comment: I have enabled Voice Memos, and I have also retried to sync my iPhone. I deleted the Voice Memos playlist in iTunes, there is no new playlist and no voice memos in iTunes. It's still not working.

Comment: @Ryan What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: I'm using 11.1.3.8

Comment: @Ryan That's iTunes; what version of iOS?

Comment: Oh yes, I'm using iOS 7.1.1 (The most up to date).

Answer (score 0):

The voice memos do not appear under "voice memos" playlist as expected; instead, they appeared when I tried:

1. Click My Device > Music
2. Scroll down the list of individual audio files/songs and voila, there were my memos mixed in with the others.

For some unknown reason, the voice memos did not end up in "Voice Memos" playlist automatically; but they can be moved there to that playlist manually.